# How exactly FLATTEN works in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

**A:**
    (1,2,3)
    (4,2,1)
    (8,3,4)
    (4,3,3)
    (7,2,5)
    (8,4,3)

**B:**
    (2,4)
    (8,9)
    (1,3)
    (2,7)
    (2,9)
    (4,6)
    (4,9)

**C:**
    (1,{(1,2,3)},{(1,3)})
    (4,{(4,2,1),(4,3,3)},{(4,6),(4,9)})
    (8,{(8,3,4),(8,4,3)},{(8,9)})

Hi friends,
For the above files A,B and C, can anyone explain what will be the result of the below statement ? 
X = FOR EACH C GENERATE FLATTEN(A.($0,$1)), FLATTEN(B.$1);

I am struggling really hard to know how flattens works.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

To gain a better understanding first do a describe on relation C and check its schema.
It should be something similar to -

```
describe C;
C: {A::group: bytearray, A: {()}, B: {()}}
```

Now you are doing a foreach on C together with a flatten, remember following as thumb rule -
**foreach with a flatten produces a cross product of every record in the bag with all of the other expressions in the generate statement.**

Now lets consider first tuple in relation C

```
(1,{(1,2,3)},{(1,3)})
```

Just for sake of better understanding I can represent this as

```
(C::1,{A::(1,2,3)},{B::(1,3)})
A.($0,$1) = (1,2)
B.($1) = (3)
```

We have only one term each for every record in bag so there would be only one cross product thus only one tuple gets in output for this iteration, i.e. (1,2,3)

Now lets consider second tuple in relation C, as shown below A has two records, B has two records, their cross product would be 2x2 = 4, hence we will see 4 records in output -

```
(C::4,{A::(4,2,1),A::(4,3,3)},{B::(4,6),B::(4,9)})
A.($0,$1) = (4,2) and (4,3)
B.($1) = (6) and (9)
--As output we will see cross product of all of the other expressions in the generate statement, hence we get
(4,2,6) (4,2,9) (4,3,6) (4,3,9)
```

Now lets see what happens with the third tuple in relation C, here A has 2 records while B has just 1 record, we get 2x1 = 2 output rows, (8,3,9) (8,4,9)

You can check more examples in book "Programming Pig"

Hope this helps.